# How to record a video from imagepicker controller deletage

Tags: iphone

I want to record a video from imagepicker controller delegate. I am getting capture image but i am not getting video mode record.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

checkout Apple's AVCAmDemo on their developer centers for custom video recording and adding custom overlay. < http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/>